# some strings in an order

Tags: string, scala

I have something like this:

```
 object OrderingCats {    
    class Cat {
        def before(that: Cat): Cat = {
          that
        }

        def after(that: Cat): Cat = {
          this
        }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val catA = new Cat
        val catB = new Cat
        val catC = new Cat

        catB before catA before catC   
       //how I can put in this order those Cat's names within a List?
    }
}
```

How I can put in a List in the same order, as the method `before` is used, the cat's names?

### Edit

I know the order of the 'cats' and I want to use a little DSL to order them through using methods `before` or `after` (it's not a big deal which one I choose to use -this is not the problem). But, then I have to get that list of ordered cats and to use for womething else. Hopefully, I am more clear now :(

Comment: Could you explain what answer you expect?

Comment: actually, I was trying to get this as a result: Array[catB, catA, catC]

Comment: Do you want your DSL for creating array similar to lists DSL? Please specify

Comment: @bkowalikpl, I wrote an explanation up, in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "in the same order". If you know the order, you can write

```
Array(catB, catA, catC)
```

If you do not know the order (and you wouldn't know whether to call `before` or `after`), you can apply an `Ordering`.

```
case class Cat(name: String)

val catA = Cat("Plato")
val catB = Cat("Admetus")
val catC = Cat("Electra")

// use implicit alphabetical Ordering[String]
List(catA, catB, catC).sortBy(_.name)
```

Or as a "DSL". Since you want to build a sequence of cats, you need at least one common way of introducing `before` to both a single cat and a collection. For example, you could treat a single cat as a collection of size one, through an implicit conversion `def single`. You could then either use an implicit class to extend the methods allowed on collections, or simply introduce your own collection wrapper `Cats` that has the DSL specific methods:

```
object Cat {
  // enable 'Cats' methods on a single cat
  implicit def single(c: Cat): Cats = new Cats(Vector(c))
}
case class Cat(name: String)

case class Cats(seq: Vector[Cat]) {
  def before(c: Cat) = Cats(seq :+ c)
  def after (c: Cat) = Cats(c +: seq)
}

val catA = Cat("Plato")
val catB = Cat("Admetus")
val catC = Cat("Electra")

catB before catA before catC
```

Comment: The answer in my question is the second part. Thanks a lot and expecially for the explanations. It's a great help!